# How to prevent the path to controller changing for Ajax code?

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net core 2 and when I call this code from the index page it works great, going to the correct EventsAPIController. It gives an url of **https://localhost:44367/api/EventsAPI/5**

```
 $.ajax({
type: "PUT",
url: "api/EventsAPI/" + event.id,
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: 'json',
```

But when I call the same code, which is in a partial View, from the another view, such as the **Events** view it fails **https://localhost:44367/Events/api/EventsAPI/5**   as the Views name is added into the path.

How do I fix this, preventing other views names entering into the URL path?

Cheers

Comment: You could prepend `/` at the front. `/api/EventsAPI/"`

Comment: Thanks, sigh, I knew it was going to be something really simple .... it works!